# any way to determine the event like mouse click for title bar in eclipse Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

i am using `eclipse rcp` and `swt` for developing application.i have a `list` and i need to set its visibility false on a movement of title bar or when  user click a `titleBar`. i am unable to find any event of `titleBar`. Is there any event of `titleBar` so that i can solve my problem? Or any thing that could probably solve my problem? i searched but could find for flex only as

```
function panelClick ( event:MouseEvent ) : void
{
    trace( event.localX + '/' + event.localY );
}
```

is there same thing for swt using eclispe.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I don't think there's a way using SWT.

Comment: @oldrinb i am using a list in a certain textBox for searching item so when a user move the application or minimze the application the list get stuck even if the windows in minized.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will output "Move" and "Minimize" when the corresponding events happen:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Button dummy = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    dummy.setText("Dummy");

    shell.addListener(SWT.Move, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            System.out.println("Move");
        }
    });

    shell.addListener(SWT.Iconify, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            System.out.println("Minimize");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();

    shell.setSize(400, 300);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

However, the `SWT.MOVE` event is only fired **after** the shell has been moved, i.e. when the "move" is over.

Comment: thanks for the answer actually i am extending the viewpart so no shell is there in my class i am looking a way to get shell from my viewpart.

Comment: @Dinupkandel Do you want to handle the events for the whole RCP? i.e. when the whole window is minimized?

Comment: i get the shell as 'Shell sh = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();' but having a problem when it ovelapped by another window beside that of application window. it is floated outside so any event to handle that.

Comment: @Dinupkandel I don't really understand your example. Maybe add a screenshot and more detail to your question.

Comment: i am near to the solution.little busy in other project. i will let you know. i will upvote you for your answer and accept if i will succed. thank Baz